# Pyglet Bordered Circle

Tags: geometry, border, shapes, pyglet

Can't find info on how to just draw a border around a circle. Simply looking to draw a circle with a black border just like the BorderedRectangle function.

```
import pyglet
from pyglet import shapes


def display_get_width():
    display = pyglet.canvas.get_display()
    screen = display.get_default_screen()
    return screen.width

def display_get_height():
    display = pyglet.canvas.get_display()
    screen = display.get_default_screen()
    return screen.height



screen_width = display_get_width()
screen_height = display_get_height()
print(screen_width, screen_height)

window = pyglet.window.Window(screen_width//2,screen_height//2)
batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

rectangle = shapes.BorderedRectangle(250, 300, 600, 300, border=1, color=(255, 255, 255), border_color=(100, 100, 100), batch=batch)
rectangle2 = shapes.BorderedRectangle(300, 350, 300, 150, border=1, color=(255, 255, 255), border_color=(100, 100, 100), batch=batch)
circle = shapes.Circle(550, 450, 100, color=(50, 225, 30), batch=batch)




@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    batch.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a year and half, but I had the same question a moment ago. I solved it by drawing shapes.ARC and setting width with a GL function:

```
pyglet.gl.glLineWidth(5)
arc = shapes.Arc(200, 200, 150, color=(255, 0, 0), batch = batch)
```

Omitting "angle" parameter while creating an Arc instance assumes angle is 2π - a full circle.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a circle inside another circle:

```py
circle = shapes.Circle(550, 450, 100, color=(50, 225, 30), batch=batch)
insideCircle = shapes.Circle(550, 450, 80, color=(30, 205, 10), batch=batch)
```